# java date time compare two

Tags: java, date

What would be the best way to compare two date in java?

Right now i have array of time like

10.00, 12.00, 2.00, 4.00

How can we find out which time to come up next compared to our computer time?

Let say right now my computer time is 3.15, what should i do to show 4.00 is next?

```
Date date = new Date();
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The java.util.Date implements the Comparable interface. That means you can very easily compare two date objects with code like this:

```
if (date1.compareTo(date2) < 0)
{
        System.out.println("date1 is before date2");
}
else if (date1.compareTo(date2) > 0)
{
    System.out.println("date1 is after date2");
}
else
{
    System.out.println("date1 is equal to date2");
}
```

Answer (score 5):

I would use [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sf.net). Create a `LocalTime` for each of the times you're interested in, and just `new LocalTime()` to get the current time of day... then you can compare them either with `compareTo` or `isBefore` and `isAfter`.

Using Joda Time instead of the built-in `Date`/`Calendar` classes will give you much more readable code for this sort of thing.

Comment: Quoting Joda: "Use of Date and Calendar leads to pain and suffering"

Answer (score 0):

JodaTime seems to be the standard answer for questions like these, but I haven't had the time (no pun intended) yet to check out Joda, so here is my Calendar suggestion:

```
public static String getNextHour() {
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar();
    int minsLeft = 60 - c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);
    c.add(Calendar.MINUTE, minsLeft);

    SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("h:mm");
    return sdf.format(c.getTime());
}
```

Comment: Both the `Calendar` class and Joda-Time were supplanted by the *java.time* classes.

Answer (score 0):

The `java.util.Date` class is the wrong type for your needs. That class represents a date *plus* a time-of-day, and you want only a time-of-day. Amongst the old date-time classes bundled with the early versions of Java there is *no* class to truly represent a time-of-day value. The [`java.sql.Time`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Time.html) class pretends to do so but is a hack.

## java.time

The [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. See [Oracle Tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). These classes were inspired by the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library. Much of the java.time functionality is [back-ported to Jave 6 & 7](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/) and further [adapted to Android](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP). These classes supplant the old date-time classes; a *vast* improvement.

The [`LocalTime`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html) class represents a time-of-day without a date and without a time zone.

Use a sorted collection such as a [`List`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) to organize your values.

```
List<LocalTime> times = new ArrayList<>( 4 );
times.add( LocalTime.of( 10 , 0 );
times.add( LocalTime.of( 12 , 0 );
times.add( LocalTime.of( 14 , 0 );
times.add( LocalTime.of( 16 , 0 );
```

Determine your sample time for comparison.

```
LocalTime sample = LocalTime.of( 15 , 15 ); // Quarter-hour past 3 in the afternoon.
```

Or get the current time-of-day. [Specify a time zone](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) as that is more reliable than implicitly depending on your JVM’s [current default time zone](http://system).

```
ZoneId zoneId = ZoneId.of( "America/Montreal" );
LocalTime sample = LocalTime.now( zoneId );
```

Loop the `List` to find the first item that is later in the day than your sample time. To compare, use the [`isAfter`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isAfter-java.time.LocalTime-), [`isBefore`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#isBefore-java.time.LocalTime-), or [`equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalTime.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) methods.

```
LocalTime hit = null;
for ( LocalTime time : times ) {
    if ( time.isAfter( sample ) ) {
        hit = time;
        break; // Bail-out of this FOR loop.
    }
}
// Test if 'hit' is still null, meaning no appropriate value found.
if ( null == hit ) { … } else ( … }
```